# Store BLOB in Docx

Tags: c#, .net, office-addins

How is it possible using C#/.NET (with Office Add-on for Office 2007/2010) to store arbitrary additional information in Docx (on-save)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use OpenXML SDK (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456489.aspx).